# Ninject/.NET MVC3 - Retriving instances of my object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

Here's some code,

```
k.Bind<IGame>().To<Game>().Named("A")
   .WithConstructorArgument("ColorChoiceCount", 12);

iGame = k.Get<IGame>("A");
((Game)iGame).SelectedColor = new GameColor(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
iGame = k.Get<IGame>("A");
```

On the first `iGame = k.Get<IGame>("A");` I get a new instance of `Game`.
Next line: I change one of it's properties.
Next line (`iGame = k.Get<IGame>("A");` again) I get a new instance again.

What I would like is to be able to retrieve instances I've already used.
But I'm totally new to this kind of tools so I guess I'm missing something.

Thank you if you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the lifetime of your object - by default the container will create a new instance.

> The available methods are as follows:
>
> - InScope
> - InTransientScope
> - InThreadScope
> - InSingletonScope
> - InRequestScope

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/03/ninject-life-cycle-management-or-scoping/

You probably want a singleton (single instance of the game):

```
k.Bind<IGame>().To<Game>().InSingletonScope().Named("A")
   .WithConstructorArgument("ColorChoiceCount", 12);
```

Comment: Correct, with a little correction: k.Bind<IGame>().To<Game>().InSingletonScope().Named("A").WithConstructorArgument("ColorChoiceCount", 12);    Thank you.